# JQuery-Django If Statement is Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, if-statement

I'm trying to add a simple popup window to my Django app. How it works is when I press the Yes button, it sends a request to my Django views. However, I want it to automatically close after I press Yes. Unfortunately, the problem with putting it directly in my "click" function is that it closes the window altogether without sending a request to my Django views.

That is why I wanted to add a variable "clicked". After the button is clicked, I want it to change the variable value to "true" so that I can run an if statement ultimately to close the window. For some reason, the popup window automatically closes when I try to open it. My guess is that the if statement is not working properly? Thank you for your help!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var clicked=false;
    var deleteid;
    $('#yes').click(function(){

        deleteid = $(this).attr("data-deleteid");
        $.get ('../../delete_function/', {delete_id:deleteid}, function(data){});
        clicked = true;
    });
    if (clicked = true){
        window.close();
    }
});
```

Comment: quite a few issues - `clicked = true` is assignment `clicked == true` is check - ALso, this needs to be checked in the `.get` method's callback.

Comment: thank you! forgot about clicked == true but how do you check in the .get method's callback?

Comment: put the code in `{}` of the call back - This check, and `clicked=true`

Comment: like this ?    $.get ('../../delete_function/', {delete_id:deleteid}, function(data){clicked=true});

Comment: Yes - Also, if this is a URL, you do not need the `../..`

Comment: The ../.. is needed for my Django app.

Comment: Hmmm, it still is not working :/ any other ideas?

Comment: correct, but if this is a URL, you dont. example `localhost:8000/delete_function/` - You dont need the `../../` Django server would prefix the server name. You just need to specify the path.

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
  var clicked = false;
  var deleteid;
  $('#yes').click(function(){
  
   deleteid = $(this).attr("data-deleteid");
   $.get ('../../delete_function/', {delete_id:deleteid},function(data){clicked=true});

  });
  if (clicked == true){
   window.close();
  }
 });

Comment: great point! i will change that! the window is still not closing

Comment: Check this: http://jsfiddle.net/9uv8u/

Comment: doesn't work still =/ and it's no longer sending any requests to my Django view function

Comment: just make sure the path is right. Example: `localhost:8000/delete_function/` is a valid URL. Also, see if there are any errors on the console log of the browser.

Answer (score 1):

Close the window in the callback function of `$.get`.

```
$.get ('../../delete_function/', {delete_id:deleteid}, function(){
    window.close();
});
```

Your `if (clicked == true)` is only running when the page is loaded, because it's not inside any event handler. At that point, the button obviously hasn't been clicked yet, so it doesn't do anything.

If you call `window.close()` directly from the click handler, it will close the window before the AJAX call has a chance to run. When you close a window, all script it was running, including any AJAX operations that were queued, are killed.

Comment: i tried another simple jquery function and it doesnt seem to work. weird how anything in that function won't do any of my jquery requests

Comment: Are you sure the AJAX call is succeeding?